# In Azure B2C Custom Policies, how do I display more than 2 distinct validation messages for validations that depend on Validation Technical Profiles?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

### Scenario

In my sign up flow, I have the requirement to show:

- an **email address** field and a **confirm email address** field
- a **password** field and a **confirm password** field

I have to validate that:

- the text entered in the email address field matches the text entered in the confirm email address field
- the text entered in the password field matches the text entered in the confirm password field
- the email address entered for a user doesn't already exist in Azure B2C

These validations should display in the existing form, rather than a new page.

The only way I've been able to display validation messages *inline* as a result of the output from Validation Technical Profiles, is by using the two built in asserts, **AssertStringClaimsAreEqual** (for the email and password comparisons) and **AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue** (for the existing user check).  These cause messages, defined in the calling Claims Provider Technical Profile, to be displayed when the assert fails.

### Problem

I have three error cases that require distinct messages, and I'm only able to define and display messages for two.  Currently, I'm working around this by displaying "Email and confirm email, or password and confirm password do not match." for both the failed text comparisons, and "This email address is already in use, please sign in." for the existing user case. The existing user case is fine, but I would describe the single text comparison message as 'Okay, but doesn't really meet the acceptance criteria' and 'I can't believe there's not a better way to do this'.

Any help would be gratefully received at this point.

### Current Code Snippets

The relevant Validation Technical Profiles:

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="EmailMatchValidator">
      <DisplayName>Check if email and confirm email match</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="DoEmailsMatch"/>
      </InputClaimsTransformations>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailsMatch" Required="true"/>
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>

    <TechnicalProfile Id="PasswordMatchValidator">
      <DisplayName>Check if password and confirm password match</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="DoPasswordsMatch"/>
      </InputClaimsTransformations>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordsMatch" Required="true"/>
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>

    <TechnicalProfile Id="UserExistsValidator">
      <DisplayName>Asset if user exists</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userExists"/>
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userExists" Required="true"/>
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="DoesUserExist"/>
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

These Technical Profiles reference Output Claims Transformations, which look like this:

```
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="DoEmailsMatch" TransformationMethod="AssertStringClaimsAreEqual">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1"/>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="confirmEmail" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2"/>
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="stringComparison" DataType="string" Value="ordinalIgnoreCase"/>
    </InputParameters>
  </ClaimsTransformation>

  <ClaimsTransformation Id="DoPasswordsMatch" TransformationMethod="AssertStringClaimsAreEqual">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1"/>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="confirmpassword" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2"/>
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="stringComparison" DataType="string" Value="ordinalIgnoreCase"/>
    </InputParameters>
  </ClaimsTransformation>

  <ClaimsTransformation Id="DoesUserExist" TransformationMethod="AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userExists" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim"/>
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="valueToCompareTo" DataType="boolean" Value="false"/>
    </InputParameters>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
```

DoEmailsMatch and DoPasswordsMatch are straightforward enough, using the AssertStringClaimsAreEqual built-in assert to display a message defined in the Metadata of the calling Claim Provider Technical Profile:

```
<Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual">Email and confirm email, or password and confirm password do not match.</Item>
```

DoesUserExist relies on AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue, which means it needs a boolean to work with, to decide whether to display the other message defined in the Metadata:

```
<Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">This email address is already in use, please sign in.</Item>
```

The code that sets that boolean is probably out of scope for this question, but in short, it gets set by a read on the AAD database that returns a matching User Principal Name in a claim, or no claim at all.  This undergoes a Claim Transformation using DoesClaimExist to set the boolean userExists claim, used by DoesUserExist above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the third one, do an AAD Read operation instead, and it has a built in error message for when the use exists.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile#ui-elements

You can find this used in the AAD B2C starter pack for the default sign up flow.

For password matching, use password and reenter password, use the built in way
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L648

Now you should only need the 1 claims transform for email matching.

Comment: Hi @Jas Suri, thank you!  The tip about using the built in password validation, rather than handrolling it, gave me what I needed.  I'd named the password reentry field 'confirmPassword' rather than 'reenterPassword', not realising reenterPassword had magic logic hidden behind it.

Comment: One more thing does occur to me, but it's not a problem for me anymore: I'm not sure the AADRead operation will raise an error if the principal already exists.  I can only get RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists working from an AADWrite.

Comment: Yes, you’re right on the read op comment, will need to use the claim transform.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that. Either way, my problem is now solved, so thanks again.